# Confusing behavior of np.random.multivariate_normal

Tags: python, numpy

I am sampling from a multivariate normal using numpy as follows.

```
mu = [0, 0]
cov = np.array([[1, 0.5], [0.5, 1]]).astype(np.float32)
np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov)
```

It gives me the following warning.

> RuntimeWarning: covariance is not positive-semidefinite.

The matrix is clearly PSD. However, when I use a **np.float64** array, it works fine. I need the covariance matrix to be **np.float32**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*This has been [fixed](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/12547) in March 2019. If you still see the warning consider updating your numpy.*

The warning is raised even for very small off-diagonal elements > 0. The default tolerance value does not seem to work well for 32 bit floats.

As a workaround pass a higher tolerance to the function:

```
np.random.multivariate_normal(mu, cov, tol=1e-6)
```

---

**Details**

[`np.random.multivariate_normal`](https://github.com/ozabluda/numpy/blob/08a02daa3f86e84df143d508949562f8881576c2/numpy/random/mtrand/mtrand.pyx#L4523) checks if the covariance is PSD by first decomposing it with `(u, s, v) = svd(cov)`, and then checking if the reconstruction `np.dot(v.T * s, v)` is close enough to the original `cov`.

With `float32` the result of the reconstruction is further off than the default tolerance of `1e-8` allows, and the function raises a warning.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, can I ignore the warning as "just a warning" and not worry about the "undefined behavior" the documentation warns about?

Comment: @AbdulFatir Yes, I would think so.

Comment: I have posted this as an [issue at numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10839). Let's see what the experts have to say about it... this might actually be a tiny bug :)